# WebSphere Application > Security role to user/group mapping - Missing

Tags: java, security, websphere, role

I'm not an expert in WebSphere.  A quick question:  I'm using WebSphere 8.5 version and installed an enterprise WAR application.  Right now I don't have any security defined in my WAR's web.xml.  Under Applications > Application types > WebSphere enterprise applications >application_name > Detail Properties, I can't see '**Security role to user/group mapping**' menu option.

What do I have to do to enable that menu option?  I'm trying to enable a BASIC authentication to one of the URLs in my application.  Found some instructions but they all refer to that menu option (Security role to user/group mapping) but can't find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option shows up as soon as your web.xml has any roles defined:

```
 <security-role>
    <role-name>testing</role-name>
 </security-role>
```

You need to exploit EE authorization in your web.xml to see these options.

Comment: Thanks covener - I tried adding this in web.xml in both deployments/../web.xml as well as one under ../cells/../web.xml.  Then bounced the server - still I don't see that menu option.  Do I need to reinstall the WAR in order to see this?

Comment: yes, generally you need to deploy it with changes, not just edit it in the filesystem.

Comment: Great - I will try this in a short-while and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes - after bouncing the server,it showed up.  Thanks a lot.